# I need to fix my php code for output result on new line

Tags: php, text, save, ip, newline

I want to save my data in my text on new line.
But I don't know how because I get ip address with IF and else.
Please help me !

```
$File = "newfile2.txt"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'a');
//whether ip is from share internet
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ))   
  {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  }
//whether ip is from proxy
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))  
  {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  }
//whether ip is from remote address
else
  {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
echo $ip_address;
fwrite($Handle, $ip_address);
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I think you need to start off with understanding how to save text first in PHP. The site isn't really for 'help me I'm stuck on this simple problem which is a product of me not bothering to learn'.

Answer (score 0):

Give EOL a try.

```
fwrite($Handle, $ip_address . PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: @pavelpavlov Glad you got it working, upvote would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I was vote but it does not reflect because I do not have a reputation.